# How to get account balance of sim in android phone

Tags: android

I need to get current account balance sim card programatically. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the account balance is actually stored on the sim-card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to access that sort of information from the SIM card in Android, sorry. You may wish to contact the mobile carrier for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is some technique to get data from sim card , it simply cant word ... because thr is  no dedicated field for balance  in a sim card ....

bt if some how you cat trace d service provider , den a possible approach can be 2 create a hashmap for main service provider's vs related number for balance inquiry => sms/call to this number =>  get response .