# How to identify current balance of particular Mobile no?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am looking to develop an android application to identify the current balance of user entered **prepaid mobile no**. **Is it possible to find current balance of that user entered mobile number?** Thanks in advance...!

Comment: I dont know why they are put the down grade.Please tell me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry android dont have any api still.
Refer this link:
[how to get account balance of sim in android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909292/how-to-get-account-balance-of-sim-in-android-phone)